# How I can spilt data from one column to other column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
WITH Test_1 AS
(
    SELECT
        chat_start_url, chat_start_date_Asia_Kolkata, 
        referrer, chat_duration_in_seconds, visitor_nick, 
        visitor_ip, visitor_email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by visitor_ip) as IP
    FROM 
        bigquery-405008.xxxx.xx_chat

SELECT *
FROM Test_1
```

I want to split data from one column to other column in same table, where column name is `chat_start_url`, which contains 2 hyperlinks and I want to split the second hyperlink into a new column.

![To know more click here][1]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide sample data that displays all likely patterns to be split.

Comment: Please check image. there are 2 different hyperlinks start from nucleu & Kernel

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was an image link. You need to learn more about preparing question here. But now I can see the image it still does NOT help; all I see is a lot of redacted data precisely hiding the details needed.

Comment: This is from site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: This might not be obvious, you can supply "sample data" (i.e. it does not have to be real data)  **provided that it represents the problem**

Comment: Done, please check again, I want to separate Kerneldatarecovery.com in other column from chat_start_url column

Comment: Are you sure it's "done" because I still see an image, not DATA. And even in that updated image you still don't display how the 2 URLs are stored in a single column. Why not just copy one value in that column as an example of the problem you want solved and paste it (as text) into your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in BigQuery. It assumes that one or more urls are concatenated in a single striong but there is no specific separator, but also it assumes that every URL starts with at least "http" (not case sensitive):

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'https://xyz.something.com/abc/xyx.htmlhttp://blah.domain.uk/text/here/and_more.asp' AS urls
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(urls, 'http') AS url
FROM data, UNNEST(SPLIT(urls, 'http')) AS urls
WHERE urls != ''
```

**nb** this approach is rudimentary and the sample above is simplistic, it probably will not meet all possible data permutations.